# Tool for Visual Studio to automatically remove methods that aren't being referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for a feature, script, or tool in Visual Studio to remove methods that aren't referenced by any code in a solution.

All my projects are in one solution (i.e. no external class libraries).

Usually I right-click on methods and choose "Find All References," and if the method declaration is the only reference, I delete he method, to help clean up the code.

For me this helps in the code analysis/reverse engineering process.

Answer (score 3):

Try ReSharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html?gclid=CN66956kqagCFQoZ4Qodexn_HA

It's not free, but it is awesome :)

Comment: Is the "Safe Delete" feature what I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, it highlights unused code in grey, and then allows you to delete it by pressing Alt+Enter, Enter when the cursor is over the grey-ed out code.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not the right thing to do, from the product perspective. If your class is being referenced by external applications, and if your public methods are being used in that external application, then by Find all References, you will not see those references in your solution.If you remove those methods, then the applications referencing your classes will be broken.(It may be the case that in your current situation this may not be the problem, but in general it would be). So i doubt if this will be a useful feature to have.

Comment: I totally understand that, but I am not concerned about that for this solution.

Comment: While I generally agree that this could be an issue with public methods in an assembly or executable that is referenced by external dependencies. In that case you might want to mark those as obsolete by using the [Obsolete] attribute on the method and not deleting it. However, in this case @JohnB stated that there are not any external dependencies "no external class libraries" and he is looking for something to use within the scope of a single solution. I agree that ReSharper is an awesome tool for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2):

[Use Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Refreactor your code with ease. Its just awesome